# Series Convergence Abstract Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the following series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ are convergent in the space $(C([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty)$, where

(i) $f_n(t)= \frac{t^n}{n!}$;

(ii)$f_n(t)=\frac{t^n}{2n}$

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The first series is uniformly convergent on any compact subset of the line (or the complex plane for that matter).  So it converges in your space

The second series is not uniformly convergent on $(-1, 1)$.  It does converge on all compact subsets of this open interval but not on the whole interval.  As a result, it does not converge in the norm you have written down.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why.. just because I still don't understand

Comment: Both are power series.  I am applying the root (or ratio) test. In the first case, the ratio test gives a constant value of zero, so that says the series converges uniformly on compacta in the complex plane.

Comment: In the second case, the root or ratio test gives a radius of convergence of 1.  Also note that at $x = 1$ the series diverges.

Comment: I haven't used the ratio test in a long time and I'm getting very confused with it... So I set $a_n= \dfrac{t^n}{n!} $ and so $a_{n+1}= \dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} $ then I have L coming out as $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{t\cdot n!}{(n+1)!}$ is that the final part which shows $\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$??